# Invalid object name in SQL Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I've been creating a database for class and I'm having trouble seeing my tables.
I have a total of 12 tables I have created, 3 via CREATE TABLE statements and the rest using the SQL Server Management Studio, I'm trying to enter an INSERT INTO statement but it's not recognizing the table that I have created.

[image]

[image]

Here are some screenshots with what I'm working with.

Comment: If this is SQL Server, why is your tag MySQL?  Please tag properly

Comment: Also you are in Master database.  There is no table TblBetaalwijzen in Master database.

Comment: You don't specify which database are the tables on. You probably created some of the tables on one database and the remaining tables on another database...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First refresh the `Tables` in your database to check whether that table existed or not.

If it does exist, check your `SQL connection` on your current session, make sure you are connecting to the correct server instance.

Comment: I refreshed every part of the server numerous times, also the cashe of the intelisense, connection is fine, build runs but wit that error, it's also the only error I get

Comment: @GerrittenNapel try to `select * From  TblBetaalwijzen` if same issue, you'd better check the table name and the connection again carefully. Be careful with the table name again, such as leading whitespace

Comment: Apparently I didn't have my database selected when I refreshed it, so you were right :)

Comment: I know this is an old post, but I have this problem too, but with Stored Procedures. The problem is not my connection and adding the DBO prefix doesn't help me. It happens as soon as I create a procedure or modify an existing one.

Comment: what kind of error did you get when trying to create the SP?

Answer (score 3):

I just saw this error on my SQL server as well. Here's how I solved it:
Problem:

```
select * from table_name;
```

error:

```
Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'table_name'
```

--> But I know it's there

Solution:

```
select * from DBname.dbo.table_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your stored procedure is not dropping your table or temp table anytime it is executed. To do so double check your Stored procedures code and make sure you comment DROP TABLE your_temp_Table or comment DROP TABLE your_Table .